# IPhone status bar double height with cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm currently building a cordova mobile app, but i'm having trouble with the status bar on the iphone, android is fine, but with IOS the status bar appears to grow to double the height.

The app is using the [Cordova StatusBar Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar), with the [StatusBarOverlaysWebView](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#configxml) setting in the `config.xml` set to false so that the app does not go behind the status bar and butts up against the top of the screen.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated. Thank you!

This is my development setup:

- Node version: **v0.12.0**
- Cordova version: **0.21.13**
- iOS platform:

  - Xcode **6.4**
  - Build version **6E35b**

**Plugins**:

- android.support.v4
- com.google.playservices
- com.googlemaps.ios,com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
- cordova-plugin-dialogs
- cordova-plugin-geolocation
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- de.appplant.cordova.common.registerusernotificationsettings
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
- nl.x-services.plugins.toast
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.file
- org.apache.cordova.media
- org.apache.cordova.statusbar
- plugin.google.maps
- plugin.http.request

Comment: First get the correct version of cordova `cordova -v` in cmd or terminal will help you. After that, do an update: run cmd as administrator or on mac `sudo npm update -g cordova`

Comment: Apps which were present on app store or which projects are created before iOS 8 launch, could face this kind of problem. Because Apple zoomed those apps to display them on iPhone 6 and 6 plus. You can try with updating cordova.

Comment: If you cannot update cordova, you can check to see which iphone model is running, and correct the scale in the viewport meta tag by setting  `minimum-scale=` and `maximum-scale=` The scale for the iphone6 (model `iPhone7,1`) is roughly 0.8533.  For iPhone6+ (model `iPhone7,2`) is roughly 0.7729.  As the others mentioned though, newer versions of Cordova should do this correctly.